# Facebook Profile Pictures are Tiny

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My iOS app fetches the profile picture for each person after they login via Facebook, using the URL `graph.facebook.com/<user id>/picture?type=large`. However, the picture coming back is often much smaller than the actual profile picture is when you see it on Facebook, sometimes around 100x150. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a `width=` or `height=` parameter instead of `type` if you want more control over the size you get back. I can't find it currently documented but in my code I noted that `type=large` means about 200px wide.